# Is there a way to convert Sencha Touch to Sencha EXTJs (or EXTJs to Touch)?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

For a project I created a ExtJS interface for a java backbone.
Now the client would also like a mobile version (mostly tablets).

The Extjs version performs alright on mobile but it is not that usable,
so I started developing the application in sencha touch.

Since this will of course take a lot of new hours, I was asked if there wasn't an easier way to "convert" a extjs application to a touch application.

I've searched the web and I can't seem to find anything on "converters".

Is there such a thing? Or is there a way I can program future applications so that the migration from one framework to another is less painful?

(obviously the views need to be rewritten, I know, but I'm talking about the rest of the application - which should be portable?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such tool to convert ExtJs to Sencha-touch and vice versa also. Actually they are not 1:1 mapped in terms of functionality and code, best you can do is to reuse model, stores & controllers(upto some extent if you are using ExtJs 4) but views have to be re-written.