# Reusing core elements between Sencha Touch and ExtJS MVC Application

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

We started a new project in which the core should be used for both; **Sencha Touch 2.2.1** Touch and **ExtJS 4.2.1** but we found two slightly different implementations in both frameworks so we wondered which one we should use.

First Sencha Touch

[image]

And ExtJS

[image]
*Where Ext.logger seems to only implement the error method*

We thought Sencha shared the core within both frameworks, didn't they? Or do we need to write even the app cores different? (which would be ridiculous! Or are there more critical differences?)

I think NO and we just overseen something here. So please help me to beat my teammates that the Sencha guys are not that stupid.

Again the Question:

**Which is the correct logging method that can be used in Sencha Touch 2.x and ExtJS 4.x and if this answer would be no are there more critical differences between Sencha Touch 2.2 MVC and ExtJS4.2 MVC which make reuse impossible?**

Comment: AFAIK, Sencha Touch and ExtJS are not designed to use the same core code.  You will find many subtle differences, like the one you have described here.  The only thing I have found that works ok for reuse between the two is `Ext.data.Model`.

Comment: @kevhender Thank you for that info and thumbs down for Sencha. What a stupid thing is that to implement to different MVC frameworks! Or what do I oversee. And I've lost the bet against my teammates :(

Comment: Just thought i will add it here that the ext 4.2.3 will see some converging between Sencha Touch and ExtJS frameworks. Have a look at "Framework directions" at: http://www.sencha.com/blog/senchacon-recap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse some bits and pieces but you will still need to change the core.

You can reuse models, stores and controllers to some extend. Everything else will have to be rewritten.

see [Is there a way to convert Sencha Touch to Sencha EXTJs (or EXTJs to Touch)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435899/is-there-a-way-to-convert-sencha-touch-to-sencha-extjs-or-extjs-to-touch)